# move command only folder items

Tags: windows

I'm trying to move all folders in "test" to the new folder "data"

move E:\test* E:\data\
but it does not work
The system cannot find the file specified.

move E:\test E:\data
this one works, but it copies also the test folder.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`move` on windows doesn't do this for some reason.

My suggestion would be to use Powershell with the `move-item` cmdlet:

```
ps> move-item e:\test\* e:\data
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for /F "delims=" %a in ('dir e:\test /a:d /b') do move "e:\test\%a" e:\data
```

Comment: why not just use `for /D`?

Comment: I am not sure, I don't think I've ever used FOR without /F :)

Answer (score 0):

Powershell (as per SvenW's answer) is best practice, but if you prefer the old fashioned command line:

```
for /D %i in (e:\test\*) do move "%i" e:\data
```

You have to double up the percent signs (i.e., use `%%i` instead of `%i`) in a batch file.